# Unbolding Notification Permission UI Alert Action Text

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, unusernotificationcenter, uialertaction

My app uses notifications and as a result it needs to ask for permissions to deliver notifications.

[image]

As you can see above, one of the options in the notification permission alert is bolded, and my goal is to unbold that text.

I know this should be achievable because other permission alerts (such as location) have unbolded action text options, like the Maps app permission below:

[image]

Unfortunately, I am not seeing a way to achieve this, as the UI alert is built and presented through the `UNUserNotificationCenter.current()` when the method `requestAuthorization` is called.

My code looks like this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't alter the text of the presented permission alert as it's get displayed by the system and there is no public api to access/edit it

Comment: Are you sure? How come the location permission alert's action buttons are both unbolded? Considering how much Apple stresses the importance of a consistent UX, it seems hard to believe that they would overlook such an obvious difference in experience between notifications and location permissions - especially since these alerts are often presented one after the other, which makes the difference in text painfully obvious.

Comment: I'll wait another couple of days for other people to answer. If there is no other satisfying answer, I will mark this as the approved answer